# Flutter Navigator pops the SimpleDialog after pressing the darkened area

Tags: flutter, dart

[The GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MDjK.gif)

The Navigator pops the SimpleDialog after pressing the darkened area as shown above in the gif.

How not to pop the SimpleDialog after pressing the darkened area?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `barrierDismissible` attribute

```
    showDialog(

     barrierDismissible: false,
     //...
```

See the doc [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html).